# Can I Use Excel VBA to Generate Alphanumeric Serial Numbers in a Quantity Specified by User Input?

Tags: excel, vba, serialization, barcode

I'm attempting to write VBA code that will allow a user to type a quantity into cell C2 on a "Dashboard" sheet, then when they click a macro button it prompts the user for an ID format and creates a sequence of serial numbers in column A of a "barcode" sheet matching that ID format. The number of serials generated is dictated by the quantity typed in cell C2 on the "Dashboard" sheet. Ideally, the macro would also incorporate the ZPL code needed to turn interpret these serials into a barcode. I've tried to borrow code from other users similar issues, but I'm not nearly competent enough with VBA to pull it off.

Using my example above, as a user I would enter "3" in cell C2 on the "Dashboard" sheet, then click a "Generate" button. An InputBox would pop up and ask me to specify the ID format for the first barcode. I input "AB0001" and click OK. The macro then runs and populates cells A1-A3 on the "barcode" sheet with :

```
"^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0001^FS^XZ"
"^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0002^FS^XZ" 
"^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0003^FS^XZ"
```

Any help with solving this puzzle is much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide more details.

I've attempted loops that add 1 to create a subsequent number in series, and attempted creating serials based on user input, but nothing seems to accomplish everything I'm trying to do. It seems possible, but my VBA coding skills leave much to be desired.

Comment: Pls. insert the code you tried in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the code starts with alphanumeric and it ends with numeric characters, would this do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateSerials(lCount As Long, sCode As String, sLocation As String)
    Dim sStart As String, sEnd As String, sFormat As String
    Dim i As Integer, r As Long, c As Integer, iNumberLength As Integer, lNumber As Long
    sStart = "^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FD"
    sEnd = "^FS^XZ"
    For i = 1 To Len(sCode)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(sCode, i, 1)) Then
           sStart = sStart & Mid(sCode, i, 1)
        Else
           If IsNumeric(Mid(sCode, i)) Then
              iNumberLength = Len(Trim(Mid(sCode, i)))
              lNumber = CLng(Trim(Mid(sCode, i)))
              sFormat = Replace(Space(iNumberLength), " ", "0")
           Else
              MsgBox "Unknown code format: " & sCode
              Exit Sub
           End If
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    r = Range(sLocation).Row
    c = Range(sLocation).Column
    For i = 1 To lCount
        Cells(r, c).Value = sStart & Format(lNumber, sFormat) & sEnd
        r = r + 1
        lNumber = lNumber + 1
    Next
End Sub
Sub test()
    '               number of serials
    '               |  code from inputbox
    '               |  |         starting cell to output serial numbers
    '               |  |         |
    GenerateSerials 3, "AB0001", "D2"
End Sub
```

Sub test will put these serials in cells D2, D3 and D4:

```
^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0001^FS^XZ
^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0002^FS^XZ
^XA^BY3,2,100^FO50,50^BC^FDAB0003^FS^XZ
```

Comment: This is extraordinarily helpful in generating the barcodes in the correct format, but two follow-up questions: Is it possible to specify a different worksheet for these barcodes to generate on and can the number of barcodes be changed with an input box for the user?

Comment: instead of Range( and Cells( use Worksheets("somesheet").Range( and Worksheets("somesheet").Cells( For an inputbox call the function with: GenerateSerials( 3, InputBox("Code"), "D2")

Comment: Obviously I can't read :-) You asked for the number of barcodes, not the code. So: GenerateSerials(InputBox("Count"), InputBox("Code"), "D2")

Comment: This helped tremendously. Thank you so much!